# How to create an .EXE file with winForms and Database SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have made an application with Visual Studio on Windows Form Application. I connected it with a Data Base SQL server and I have a question. How to create .EXE file which contains both (WinForms and Sql server Db), when the Users runs the .EXE file. They need to get the Windows Form App and DB if the Users dont have SQL server installed.

Comment: The database should run on the computer, where the EXE is running? If yes, try using local database *.sdf instead of the current.

Comment: Yes that is what Im searching for using a local database. My files are .mdf file. Could you tell me how to make them .sdf ?

Comment: I guess you need an [embedded database](http://embedded-databases.com/). Note Sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use local database `*.sdf` by **right click on project > Add > New Item > section Data > Local database**

OR

Use remote database deployed on a database server and simply connect to it.

Comment: Thank you, but in section Data i dont have Local database. Im working on Vs 2015 and what extension should i install to have Local database.

Comment: I use VS2015 Prof, too. I have it by default... What version are you using?

Comment: Try following http://yakimadev.com/how-to-add-sql-server-compact-database-sdf-to-visual-studio-2013-project/

Comment: Im on VS 2015 Community and thanks for the link. I created .sdf DB but I think my connectionString is wrong. I mean the winforms builds and after displaying the design it cant get anything from the new DB. Any Ideas and thanks

Comment: `Data Source=MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;` (https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/)

Comment: Thanks, a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Errr, you can't.

SQL Server is a large, sophisticated database application.  You can't just bundle a version of this inside your .exe file, if the user doesn't have SQL Server installed.

Your best bet... deploy your SQL Server database to Azure.  Then the users will definitely have access to your database (assuming they're connected to the internet).